# Breeze.Net Connecting to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

Okay going to try to keep the fluff to a minimum. First we are new to Breeze.  We have a project where the "Database First" Entity Framework was created.  Using the SPA approach for offline webpage with AngularJS/BreezeJS combination.  Angular seems to be working fine and as stated the Entity Framework EDMX file already exists.

Can I connect Breeze.Net to our Entity Framework and if so are there any examples of this specifically the Server side connection part?  But the full example would be best.  aka  Entity Framework to Breeze.Net to BreezeJS

If I cannot connect Breeze to my Entity Framework, can I do a "Database First" Breeze.Net approach and if yes is there an example of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Breeze documentation includes [many pertinent samples](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples) including the most basic [Angular Todo](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/todo-angular) sample.  Among the samples, "DocCode" has the most sophisticated .NET Web API / EF variations (you can mentally translate from Knockout to Angular for the front-end).

You can download or clone them all [from github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples).

Most (if not all) EF samples rely on a code-first model but you should have no trouble with a `DbContext` generated "DB First" (or with an old-school `ObjectContext`).

Comment: DocCode is all code first. I haven't used db first in years. I'm not taking a position on that subject. That's just me. But I know that our breeze internal test do include a db first edmx which is why I am confident it works. Those are a big pile of tests that wont be easy to explain (they aren't for general audiences). So I'm suggesting that you simply use the `DbContext` that you get from your db first code gen exactly as we show in our samples. If you have a more specific issue THEN, you'll be able to give us something we can chew on.

Comment: Got the final answer from IdeaBlade and it was as simple as I thought it would be will be posting that up tomorrow out of time today.